# How can I get information on the author of changes pushed / pulled?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I work on multiple machines, and I'm trying to figure out which one has the potential problem from some changes I pushed. Is there a way to get the machine name / IP address or any other ID of the changes pushed?

Comment: If the different machines have different author/committer names/emails set in git config, you'll be able to distinguish them. And only if.

Comment: If you're interested in determining which machine you created a commit on, and all the machines are under your own control, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35261086/184546) may help you. (And I just added an answer which would address your specific need.)

Comment: @TTT Searching local reflogs is indeed a possibility I didn't think of, great idea.